# ng-2 charts stacked bar

Tags: angular, charts, angular5, ng2-charts

Is it even possible to stack bars with ng2-charts?

I get that you have to set stacked to true:

```
scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        stacked: true
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
```

But to from here I'm kind of lost, I've even tried to get it working with a static dataset

```
chartData = [{ data: [452,645], label: this.dataSetLabel, stack: '1' },{ data: [45,65], label: this.dataSetLabel, stack: '1' }];
```

Am I missing something totally obvious? Any leads is appreciated.